# Android studio does not generate APK

Tags: android, android-studio

I just switched from using Eclipse to Android Studio, and everything has been great, until I tried generating the APK from a project I began in Eclipse. I enter all the keystore information to create a signed APK, but after it compiles I get a file with no extension type.
It will not run on other devices. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I get a file with no extension type

Just add the extension ".apk" to it then.

Comment: surprised that worked, and also that the build doesn't automatically include the .apk extension. Thanks